# Editing the LaunchScreen.storyboard on Google Place Picker Demo

Tags: ios, xcode, google-places-api

I have been trying to implement the Google Places API and stumbled upon the Place Picker Demo provided by Google. I have been trying to edit the code and tailor it to my project but to no avail. For example I tried changing the launchscreen.storyboard file to fit my needs, but in the simulator it shows up for about a second before it goes back the original app screen. So is it even possible to edit the demo code that Google has created or transfer it to my project somehow? I am also quite new to Swift and Xcode so any help would be appreciated.

This is the link to where I obtained the code from:
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/code-samples

Answer (score 0):

The `LaunchScreen.storyboard` interface is only shown for a split second while the app is loading and should not contain any actual content besides a logo or a barebones preview interface (Apple discourages logos) so that the app appears to have a fast start time.

On the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/):

> A launch screen appears instantly when your app starts up. The launch
>   screen is quickly replaced with the first screen of your app, giving
>   the impression that your app is fast and responsive. The launch screen
>   isn’t an opportunity for artistic expression. It’s solely intended to
>   enhance the perception of your app as quick to launch and immediately
>   ready for use.

If you want to have a different starting screen, add a View Controller to the `Main.storyboard` and set it as the Initial View Controller (a checkbox in the right sidebar).

[image: Initial view controller option]